# Communication through Data Layer synchronization

Tags: wear-os

I'm developing an app that have a wear side and a handheld side. The App is meant to work without the handheld side and sync the data acquired when the two sides connect. Right now I have a service on the handheld side that is listening the googleclientAPI and on the wear side I have a service that acquires GPS data and put every coordinate on the googleclientAPI. When I run the wear side (without handheld connection) the app adds all the data to the googleclientAPI as I want.

The thing is that when I connect both sides (trough Bluetooth) the handheld side only receives the LAST dataMap added to the googleClientAPI...

Wear Side:

```
private void addLocationEntry(double latitude, double longitude, float accuracy, long gpsTime, float speed, double altitude, long time){
    String PATH = "/TuneWear/GPSdata";

    if(!googleClient.isConnected()){
        return;
    }

    String path = PATH + "/" + time;
    PutDataMapRequest putDataMapRequest = PutDataMapRequest.create(path);

    putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putLong(KEY_GPSTIME, gpsTime);
    putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putLong(KEY_TIME, time);
    putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putDouble(KEY_LATITUDE, latitude);
    putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putDouble(KEY_LONGITUDE, longitude);
    putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putFloat(KEY_SPEED, speed);
    putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putFloat(KEY_DISTANCE, distance);
    putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putFloat(KEY_ACCURACY, accuracy);
    putDataMapRequest.getDataMap().putDouble(KEY_ALTITUDE, altitude);

    PutDataRequest request = putDataMapRequest.asPutDataRequest();

    Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(googleClient, request);

    mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

Handheld Side:

```
@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEventBuffer) {
    for (DataEvent event : dataEventBuffer) {
        if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_CHANGED) {
            // DataItem changed
            DataItem item = event.getDataItem();
            //Log.d(TAG, "DataItem RECEIVED: " + item.getUri().getPath());
            if (item.getUri().getPath().contains(PATH + "/")) {
                DataMap dataMap = DataMapItem.fromDataItem(item).getDataMap();
                Log.d(TAG, "DataItem " + item.getUri().getPath() + " changed: GPSTimestamp " + dataMap.getLong(KEY_GPSTIME) + " Time: " + dataMap.getLong(KEY_TIME) +
                        " LAT " + dataMap.getDouble(KEY_LATITUDE) + " LONG " + dataMap.getDouble(KEY_LONGITUDE) + " Speed: " + dataMap.getFloat(KEY_SPEED) +
                        " Distance: " + dataMap.getFloat(KEY_DISTANCE) + " Accuracy: " + dataMap.getFloat(KEY_ACCURACY) + " Altitude: " + dataMap.getDouble(KEY_ALTITUDE));


                String headerString = "GPSTimestamp\tPhoneTimestamp\tLatitude\tLongitude\tSpeed\tDistance\tAccuracy\tAltitude\n";
                String dataPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/TuneWear/";
                String dataString = dataMap.getLong(KEY_GPSTIME) + "\t" + dataMap.getLong(KEY_TIME) + "\t" + dataMap.getDouble(KEY_LATITUDE) + "\t" +
                        dataMap.getDouble(KEY_LONGITUDE) + "\t" + dataMap.getFloat(KEY_SPEED) + "\t" + dataMap.getFloat(KEY_DISTANCE) + "\t" + dataMap.getFloat(KEY_ACCURACY) +
                        "\t" + dataMap.getDouble(KEY_ALTITUDE) + "\n";

                File myDir = new File(dataPath + PATH);
                myDir.mkdirs();

                File file = new File(myDir, "data.txt");
                Log.i("FILE", "FILE: " + file.getPath());
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
                    if(file.length() == 0){
                        out.write(headerString.getBytes());
                    }
                    out.write(dataString.getBytes());
                    out.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
                }
                Log.i("FILE", "FILE Changed!!! ");
            }
        } else if (event.getType() == DataEvent.TYPE_DELETED) {
            // DataItem deleted
            Log.d(TAG, "DataItem deleted: " + event.getDataItem().getUri());
        }
        //Wearable.DataApi.deleteDataItems(mGoogleApiClient, event.getDataItem().getUri(), DataApi.FILTER_PREFIX);

    }
}
```

How can I make all the data be synchronized?

Comment: Are you certain  that each time you call addLocationEntry, you are passing a new "time" parameter?

Comment: No, I'm passing the same "time" every time!!! Is that why it only updates the last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the same "time", it means your data items all have the same exact path, then each addition updates the old data so you'll end up with only one record (the last one). If you want all to be available separately, make sure their paths are unique (say, use a timestamp in your path).

Comment: Internal data leak within a DataBuffer object detected!  Be sure to explicitly call release() on all DataBuffer extending objects when you are done with them. (com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataItemBuffer@fd2a021)

What item I need to "release()"?

Comment: dataEventBuffer needs to be released after you are done with it